# ExcelDataReader changing columns name

Tags: excel, vb.net, exceldatareader

I am reading an Excel file using ExcelDataReader

```
Dim entireExcel As DataTableCollection

Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx|Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls"}
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    txtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName

        Using stream = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName)
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
            Dim reader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
            entireExcel = reader.AsDataSet(New ExcelDataSetConfiguration() With {
                             .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration() With {
                             .UseHeaderRow = True}}).Tables
        End Using
    End If
End Using
```

It all works fine, with one exception: The column names in the sheets are not the real ones in Excel. If the column is a duplicate of a column to the left, it adds _1, _2, etc., to the name. If the column name is missing, it creates a name Column0, Column1, Column2, etc.

How can I get the real names, or how can I prevent changing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for this behaviour is the implementation of DataSet throws a `DuplicateNameException` if you try to set duplicate column names [1]. ExcelDataReader works around this by generating the unique names for you.

You need to find a workaround depending on your case. F.ex set `UseHeaderRow` to false and read the column names manually from the data. Or don't use `AsDataSet()` at all, but instead rely on the reader's `Read()`/`GetValue()`/`GetXXX()` methods.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.columnname